# Can I add rules to ML.NET?

Tags: .net, machine-learning, ml.net

From all the examples I have been seeing from ML.NET, the structure goes as such,

1. Give it a Training Dataset.
2. Train it.
3. Evaluate it against a Test Dataset.
4. Then give it a the real data, and based on what it learned from the training dataset, it will give you a result.

But what if I want to add custom rules?

For instance, I have a ton of if-else condition, and I would want to substitute it with a decision tree algorithm through machine learning, for this I am using ML.NET. I have multiple attributes, and based on the attribute my answer will be either yes or no.

I do not understand it here, is it just as simple as training with a set of data and getting a result?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to look like a transformer. You can add your transformer via *ITransformer* interface. But you must provide that transformer with your model.

https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/docs/code/MlNetHighLevelConcepts.md